# Get the date of one week from today

Tags: php, date

How do I get the date, one week from today, in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD ?

Comment: Predicting 4-5 examples of `strtotime` and exactly one example doing `time` and second multiplication.

Comment: For your reading pleasure:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @Blender: It is add a week from today (I think) I think it's little bit more clear with the edit(?).

Answer (score 115):

Try:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 week"));
```

This will output:

```
2015-12-31
```

If today is 2015-12-24

Comment: Somehow that doesn't work for me... Did it change recently?

Comment: just used it - date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 week')); works fine in PHP 7 to give one week from now.

Answer (score 24):

Just so Charles' prediction is wrong, here's a PHP 5.3+ example:

```
$now = new DateTime;
$interval = new DateInterval('P1W')
$next_week = $now->add($interval);
echo $next_week->format('Y-m-d');
```

or in slightly more compact form:

```
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->add(new DateInterval('P1W'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: @Charles I think your bets are meant to show that you knew exactly what answers were to expect, however I have not seen any of your own solutions here. Thankfully the other members did not feel this question to be below their pay grade. I think this is what OverStack is all about -- not betting. What do you think?

Comment: @santa, the problem is that questions *very similar* to yours have been asked *[hundreds](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%2Badd+%2Bweek) to [thousands](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%2Bweek)* of times before.  Take a peek at the "Related" list of questions to the right.  Click in to a few of them.  You'll find that they have answers remarkably similar to those here.  These questions would have shown up during the question creating process and would have shown up after a quick search.  *Please* search the site *first* the next time you have a question.

Comment: @Charles Yes It was cheek in mouth for me, but I would like just to point out that it is the dynamics that makes this site great, its not a wiki.

Answer (score 9):

```
<?php
$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', $nextWeek) ."\n";
```

One missing from Charles prediction, [straight from the horses mouth, example #1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

Answer (score 9):

**adding days, weeks, months to any date**

```
 $date = date("Y-m-d");// current date

 $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day");

 $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 week");

 $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +2 week");

 $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 month");

 $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +30 days");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    for ($i=0 ; $i < 7 ;$i++)
    {
        $date[]=date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+{$i} day",time()));
    }

    print_r($date);
```