# Get a list of this week dates

Tags: php, html, datetime, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to find the dates between two dates specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736784/how-to-find-the-dates-between-two-dates-specified)

I want to get todays date and the following 6 days. I wish to display it as an html list. So say today date is the 1st October I would like to return.

```
<ul>
        <li>01/10/2011</li>
        <li>02/10/2011</li>
        <li>03/10/2011</li>
        <li>04/10/2011</li>
        <li>05/10/2011</li>
        <li>06/10/2011</li>
        <li>07/10/2011</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Related: [Get the date of one week from today with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5628735)

Comment: As a one liner - `<option><?php for($i=0;$i<7;$i++) echo "\t<li>" . date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+$i days")) . "</li>\r\n"; ?></option>
`

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP Documentation:

> It is possible to use date() and mktime() together to find dates in the future or the past.

```
<?php
$tomorrow  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"));
$lastmonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d"),   date("Y"));
$nextyear  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),   date("d"),   date("Y")+1);
?>
```

See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).