# I am trying to write a simple Web App for guitar teachers using PHP, mySQL, and EXTjs

Tags: php, mysql, extjs3

I am working on a project for school/myself. This is the project description...

"I am thinking of starting a guitar teaching business and would like to create a web app that would enable me to keep track of students, their lesson schedule, musical interests, payment history, age, e-mail address, and phone number. I would also like to be able to create a record of what information we went over in a lesson, along with a list of skills the student currently has or has developed over time. When a student makes their monthly payment I would like to be able to click process payment and e-mail a copy of the invoice to the student, and to myself. For upkeep of student records I would use an edit button to update the information after each lesson."

We have to use EXTjs as our presentation layer, PHP as out logic layer, and mySQL as our database.

I feel pretty confident in being able to populate my grids and the layout of the page. ***I am however worried about being able to make sure I can generate a date that a student is supposed to have their next lesson (example, today is April 8th, this students next class would be April 15th, then the 22nd etc.)***

I haven't started my PHP code yet, I am wondering if anyone could point me in the correct direction because I really have no idea how I would do what I want to do based of off the date a student began.

My database code is given below.

```
use mydatabase;

drop table teacher;
drop table student; 
drop table payment;
drop table skills;
drop table TeacherTrainingLog; 
drop table StudentTrainingLog;


CREATE TABLE teacher
    (TeacherID int,
    TeacherLast varchar(30), 
    TeacherFirst varchar(30),
    TeacherEmail varchar(254),
    TeacherDOB date, 
    TeacherAddress varchar(50), 
    TeacherCity varchar(30), 
    TeacherState char(2), 
    TeacherZip varchar(10), 
    TeacherPhone varchar(12), 
    TeacherUserId varchar(50), 
    TeacherPassword varchar(15));
alter table teacher add constraint TeacherPK primary key (TeacherID); 


CREATE TABLE student
    (StudentID int,
    StudentLast varchar(30), 
    StudentFirst varchar(30),
    StudentEmail varchar(254),
    DateStarted date, 
    StudentDOB date,
    MusicInterest text, 
    StudentAddress varchar(50), 
    StudentCity varchar(30), 
    StudentState char(2), 
    StudentZip varchar(10), 
    StudentPhone varchar(12), 
    StudentUserId varchar(50), 
    StudentPassword varchar(15),
    TeacherID int);
alter table student add constraint StudentPK primary key (StudentID); 
alter table student add constraint TeacherFK foreign key (TeacherID) references teacher(TeacherID);



CREATE TABLE payment
    (PaymentID int,
    PaymentDueDate date,
    PaymentAmount int,
    TeacherID int,
    StudentID int);
alter table payment add constraint PaymentPK primary key (PaymentID); 
alter table payment add constraint TeacherFK foreign key (TeacherID) references teacher(TeacherID);
alter table payment add constraint StudentFK foreign key (StudentID) references student(StudentID);


CREATE TABLE skills
    (SkillID int,
    SkillName varchar(30));
alter table skills add constraint SkillPK primary key (SkillID);


CREATE TABLE TeacherTrainingLog
    (TeacherID int,
    SkillID int,
    TeacherDateStarted date,
    Teacherlevel int,
    TeacherTrainingNotes text);
alter table TeacherTrainingLog add constraint TeachIDfk foreign key (TeacherID) references teacher (TeacherID); 
alter table TeacherTrainingLog add constraint SkillIDfk foreign key (SkillID) references skills (SkillID); 
alter table TeacherTrainingLog add constraint TeacherTraingingLogPK primary key (TeacherID, SkillID); 

CREATE TABLE StudentTrainingLog
    (StudentID int,
    SkillID int,
    StudentDateStarted date,
    Studentlevel int,
    StudentTrainingNotes text);
alter table StudentTrainingLog add constraint StudentIDfk foreign key (StudentID) references student (StudentID); 
alter table StudentTrainingLog add constraint SkillIDfk foreign key (SkillID) references skills (SkillID); 
alter table StudentTrainingLog add constraint StudentTraingingLogPK primary key (StudentID, SkillID); 



insert into teacher values (1, 'Bob', 'Joe','teacher.troxy@gmail.com','1988/5/4', '1120 Sweet St.', 'Boulder', 'CO', '55555', '555-555-5555','capn', 'crunch');

insert into student values (1, 'Joey', 'Bobby','student.troxy@gmail.com','2013/4/8', '1988/9/12', 'Led Zepplin, Taylor Swift', '2120 Garbage Can Ln', 'Boulder', 'CO', '55555', '333-333-333','student1', 

'first', 1);

insert into skills values (1, 'Chord');
insert into skills values (2, 'Strumming');
insert into skills values (3, 'Alternate Picking');
insert into skills values (4, 'Bend');
insert into skills values (5, 'Bend/Release');
insert into skills values (6, 'Hammer-on');
insert into skills values (7, 'Pull-off');
insert into skills values (8, 'Slide');
insert into skills values (9, 'Vibrato');
insert into skills values (10, 'Tapping');
insert into skills values (11, 'Natural Harmonic');
insert into skills values (12, 'Pinch Harmonic');
insert into skills values (13, 'Sweep Picking');
insert into skills values (14, 'Finger Picking');
```

Thanks for any help you can give to me. I hope this was not to vague. I tried to explain it as well as I know how.

Comment: Is it something like this you're after? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628735/get-the-date-of-one-week-from-today-with-php
Welcome to StackOverflow by the way :)

Comment: @Whistletoe Thanks for the welcome and the reply! With this sort of code would I be able assign particular days each week to a student? My goal is to have a schedule generate in a grid on the left of the site so you could see what students were coming in for the day and things like that.

Comment: Your database is irrelevant to figuring out when a students next lesson is, that is calculated by your php code.

Comment: @TobyAllen Thanks. I know the Database isn't extremely relevant. I did want to show how I was storing the data for the DateStarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the lesson will be weekly from the starting date, you could do something like this in MySQL to get the next lesson from their starting date:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(DateStarted, INTERVAL 7 DAY) FROM `StudentID` WHERE StudentID = ?;
```

But really what you probably want is for any given student to know when their next lesson is. It probably *won't* be dependent on their start date, and lesson days/times change with people's schedules, so I would recommend just having a db table with lesson date/time tied by StudentID. You could populate the table using a form where you could select the student, enter a date range and the date & time of the lessons, hit go, and your PHP script would enter the lesson dates into the table. ...or you could enter them by hand.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer that is most helpful and good luck with your project! - sounds like fun! Feel free to contact me if you end up needing help with the PHP.

Comment: Are you around tonight? I'm working on my PHP and it is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed intervals, why not save the weekday and lession time for each student?

Create a new table called 'lession' and connect student id and teacher id. Each row then has lession id, student id, teacher id, weekday, and time.