# How To Get Next Wednesday With PHP?

Tags: php

I have this situation :

**17 January 2017 is Tuesday.**

I'm expecting my code will generate 25 January 2017 as NEXT Wednesday. Not 18 January 2017.

**19 January 2017 is Thursday.**

I'm expecting my code will generate 25 January 2017 as NEXT Wednesday too.

but this code :

```
$payment_date = '17 January 2017';
echo $payment_date . '<br>';

$payment_date = date('d M Y', strtotime('next Wednesday', strtotime($payment_date)));
echo $payment_date;
```

gives me 18 January 2017 as next Wednesday. how to get 25 January 2017 as next Wednesday when my code runs between 15 - 21 January 2017?

thank you

Comment: Why same code does not fit for `15 - 21 January 2017`?

Comment: @Justinas : `$payment_date = '17 January 2017';` try to change that line. into 15, 16, 17, etc

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628735/get-the-date-of-one-week-from-today-with-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$payment_date = date('d M Y', strtotime('next wednesday next week', strtotime($payment_date)));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `+1 week Wednesday` instead of `Next Wednesday`:

```
$payment_date = date('d M Y', strtotime('+1 week Wednesday', strtotime($payment_date)));
```

Comment: `$payment_date = '19 January 2017';` will generate 01 Feb 2017 as next Wednesday, instead of 25 January 2017.